# HTML table header continues to be repeated for each row in the table

Tags: php, html, html-table

For someone may be nonsense, but neither are some days that I can get on top.
I have this code that I create a table from a query I would like the column header was repeated each line.

```
$contenuto="<table align = center width=80% border=2> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
<tr> <th>Data</th> 
<th>Cognome</th>  
<th>Nome</th>  
<th>Data di Nascita</th>  
<th>Luogo di nascita</th>  
<th>Luogo del fatto</th>  
<th>Ora</th>  </tr><br /> 
</thead> "; 

while ($riga = mysql_fetch_assoc($risultato)) { 

$contenuto .= "<td>".$riga["data"]."</td>"; 
$contenuto .= "<td>".$riga["cognome"]."</td>"; 
$contenuto .= "<td>".$riga["nome"]."</td>"; 
$contenuto .= "<td>".$riga["data_nasc"]."</td>"; 
$contenuto .= "<td>".$riga["luogo"]."</td>"; 
$contenuto .= "<td>".$riga["luogo_fatto"]."</td>"; 
$contenuto .= "  <td>".$riga["ora"]."</td>"; 
$contenuto .= "<tr><th colspan='14' align = center>Fatto</th><tr><td    colspan='14' align = center>".$riga["fatto"]."</td></tr>"; 
$contenuto .= " <tr><th colspan='14'>Descrizione del fatto</th></tr><tr><td colspan='14' align = justify>".$riga["descri"]."</td></tr>"; 

}
```

How can I do?

Comment: no <tr> tag in your loop before the first <td>s

Answer (score 1):

This one will help you simply you can place the header part with in it

```
 echo "<table align = center width=80% border=2>";  
 $contenuto="<thead> 
     <tr> <th>Data</th> 
     <th>Cognome</th>  
      <th>Nome</th>  
       <th>Data di Nascita</th>  
       <th>Luogo di nascita</th>  
      <th>Luogo del fatto</th>  
       <th>Ora</th>  </tr>
       </thead> "; 

      while ($riga = mysql_fetch_assoc($risultato)) { 
          echo $contenuto.  "<td>".$riga["data"]."</td><td>".$riga["cognome"]."</td><td>".$riga["nome"]."</td><td>".$riga["data_nasc"]."</td> <td>".$riga["luogo"]."</td><td>".$riga["luogo_fatto"]."</td><td>".$riga["ora"]."</td> </tr>

       <tr><th colspan='14' align = center>Fatto</th></tr>

        <tr><td    colspan='14' align = center>".$riga["fatto"]."</td></tr>

          <tr><th colspan='14'>Descrizione del fatto</th></tr><tr><td colspan='14' align = justify>".$riga["descri"]."</td></tr>"; 
         }
```

You have missed few tr tags. I added those two. This one will help you sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the code inside the while..

```
while ($riga = mysql_fetch_assoc($risultato)) { 

    <thead> 
       <tr> 
         <tr> <th>Data</th> 
          <th>Cognome</th>  
          <th>Nome</th>  
          <th>Data di Nascita</th>  
          <th>Luogo di nascita</th>  
          <th>Luogo del fatto</th>  
          <th>Ora</th>  </tr><br /> 
    </thead> ";                 


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$head='*head html sentence*';
```

while ($riga = mysql_fetch_assoc($risultato)) {

```
$contenuto .= $head;
$contenuto .= "<td>".$riga["data"]."</td>"; 
$contenuto .= "<td>".$riga["cognome"]."</td>"; 
$contenuto .= "<td>".$riga["nome"]."</td>"; 
$contenuto .= "<td>".$riga["data_nasc"]."</td>"; 
$contenuto .= "<td>".$riga["luogo"]."</td>"; 
$contenuto .= "<td>".$riga["luogo_fatto"]."</td>"; 
$contenuto .= "  <td>".$riga["ora"]."</td>"; 
$contenuto .= "<tr><th colspan='14' align = center>Fatto</th><tr><td    colspan='14' align = center>".$riga["fatto"]."</td></tr>"; 
$contenuto .= " <tr><th colspan='14'>Descrizione del fatto</th></tr><tr><td colspan='14' align = justify>".$riga["descri"]."</td></tr>";
```

}